# Windows 7 у приложений нет доступа к интернету (steam, rockstar launcher)

Tags: windows

Переустановил Windows 7 х64 (использую так как 4гб ram), возникла сложность. Приложения не имеют доступ к интернету, установщик .net framework, steam, rockstar games launcher не имеют доступа к интернету. Браузеры работают без проблем.

Система чистая, пробовал переустановить драйвер ethernet модуля на версию из бэкап файлов сохраненные перед переустановкой, изменений нет. В чем может быть причина? и как же решить эту проблему?

Comment: наверное нужно обновить систему, чтобы обновились сертификаты, но для этого нужно вручную установить `Windows Update Agent 7.6`

Comment: Вы были правы. Установка обновлений решило проблему

Answer (score 1):

Решением проблемы оказалось установка множества обновлений ОС с момента выхода по настоящее время.